# Is there a classification model with possibility to set transition probabilities for each sample?

Tags: time-series, machine-learning, classification

There are models where we can to set initial transition probabilities between  classes like Markov models. But what if we need to change the probabilities dynamically depends on all previous classifier decisions and/or some external factors.

I am trying to classify some time series and I would like to use knowledge domain heuristics for changing the transition probabilities of a current sample depends on all previous decisions.

What classifier may help in this situation?